# mediaelement.js - how to play from Cloudfront

Tags: mediaelement.js

I would like to be able to stream mp4 video files from cloudfront - how do I set this up in mediaelement?

Comment: Remember to set the ContentType header to video/mp4 and an Expiry header or you may have problems with playing and re-downlaoding

Answer (score 1):

Just point the src to your cloudfront distribution URL and you're all set:

```
 <video src="http://mycloudfront.com/myfile.mp4"></video>
```

You'll want to make sure you also add a crossdomain.xml to your Amazon S3 for Flash fallback mode.

Comment: what should I do if I want to stream video from my cloudfront? Using JW player I can set up 'streamer':'rtmp://mycloudfront.net/' and 'file':'mp4:myfilename'. can I do the same with mediaelementjs somehow? thanks.